# "fastfwd" file that can be pipe/socket/fifo

Tags: c++, c, file-io, fseek

My function gets a `FILE*` to read from, and it needs to read starting from some non-negative offset.
I could use `fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET)`, but it fails on `stdin`, for instance.

How can I determine if `fseek` works? If it doesn't, I could read and discard `offset` bytes.

And is there a way to read (and discard) from `FILE` without allocating read buffer?

Comment: Maybe if you add a little code it would be clearer what you're trying to ask..

Comment: Give `FILE* file`, how do I check that `fseek` will work on this `file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if fseek works on that stream, by calling `fseek( file, offset, SEEK_SET)` and on error, checking that `errno == EBADF`   which is returned to say "The stream specified is not a seekable stream".

I think you need to read and discard, with a buffer, but if it can just be pagesize bytes and you keep a count of bytes read, reading till you did the equivalent of a seek.  If it were a memory mappable file, then you can read without reading, but then the seek would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [`fseek()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) tells you if it worked or not:

> > > Return Value
> > >       ...Upon successful completion, fgetpos(), fseek(), fsetpos() return 0, ...Otherwise, **-1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.**

So attempt to `fseek()` from the file and check the return result, and handle your failure case accordingly. Ex:

```
ret = fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_SET);
if(ret < 0)
    printf("failed because: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

will give you something like:

```
failed because: Illegal seek
```

So that failed because you can't seek `stdin`, where as:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("word.txt", "r");
ret = fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
if(ret < 0)
    printf("failed because: %s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Wouldn't print anything because you got back `0` indicating success (assuming of course that `"word.txt"` exists, is readable, was opened successfully, etc).

I don't understand this part of your question:

> > is there a way to read (and discard) from FILE without allocating read buffer

You can just `fseek()` to the point you want to read, or you can read into an array to a buffer and then overwrite the results. The answer depends on your goals, but using things like [`fread()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) or [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) will require a non-null pointer to store data into.